# User feedback while uploading large files

Tags: file-upload, modal-dialog, user

I currently have an asset library setup to allow users to collaborate with short video clips, a maximum of 250MB.  These clips have a short lifespan and retention is set to 10 days.

While this all appears to work as expected I find that uploading of larger files causes confusion as no feedback is provided to the user when they click the "OK".  Instead the following screen is show until the entire file has completed upload:

[image: Upload Document Dialog]

Is it possible to provide user notification that "OK" click has been accepted and the upload is processing?  Ideally I would like to see a spinner and a note saying "processing".

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into `SPLongOperation`?  You can implement this in the code-behind of the aspx upload page. It will display the *circle-of-wait* until the file process is complete.

[image]

You can provide a custom message, and when it's done the operation can redirect your user too

```
// BEGIN long-running operation
SPLongOperation lop = new SPLongOperation(this.Page);
lop.LeadingHTML = "<div><h2>Your enormous file is being uploaded...</h2></div>";
lop.TrailingHTML = "<div><h3>Please be patient</h3></div>";
lop.Begin();

// your long operation code here

// END long-running operation
lop.End(spTargetListObject.DefaultViewUrl, Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPRedirectFlags.Default, this.Context, "");
```

Here'a a helpful blog about it http://howtosharepoint.blogspot.com/2010/04/how-to-programatically-show-processing.html

Answer (score 0):

This is totally possible using some basic css or javascript (and maybe JQuery to spiff it up) attached to the okay button (onClick)

Here's a generic spinner example you could work from: http://jquery-plugins.net/spin-js-spinning-activity-indicator

Comment: Down vote but no comment for a reason why? I've done this exact thing before and it works just fine.